# C# EXT direct method return undefined value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a direct method which gets 2 arguments and returns a value (string). While I can see that the direct method is called and the return value "result" is as expected (the alert function prints it with the correct value), the value in the HTML is 'undefined'

```
        [DirectMethod]
        public string callFNGetPtidPrfx(int siteid, int ptid)
        {
            DAL.CDataContext dc = new CDataContext();
            return dc.fn_GetPtid(100, siteid, ptid);
        }
```

---

```
Handler="
    this.body.dom.innerHTML = String.format('{0}',(#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('PtId') !=null? #{DirectMethods}.callFNGetPtidPrfx(#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('SiteId'),#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('PtId'),{
                 success: function (result) {
                     alert(result);
                     return result;  
                 }
             }):'-')
```

**EDIT:**
Artem Stepin's solution worked. The only thing is that the first time its called the html is not formatted correctly... Please take a look at the screenshots

[image: First time its called][image: after first time]

Here is the full code I used:

```
<Show Handler="
            try{
                var rowIndex = #{QueriesGridPanel1}.view.findRowIndex(this.triggerElement);
                var me = this;
                #{DirectMethods}.callFNPtidPrfx(#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('SiteId'),#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('PtId'),{
                    success: function (result) { 
                        me.body.dom.innerHTML = String.format('{0}<hr />{1} <br /><br /><i>{2} level query<br />Link to:{3}|{4}|{5}|{6}|{7}<br />Created By: {8}, {9}</i> ', 
                        '<i>'+#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('CreatedBy') +':</i><b> '+ #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('Message')+'</b>', 
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('ResolvedBy') !=null? '<i><u>'+#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('ResolvedBy') +'</u>: </i><b>' + #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('comment')+'</b>':''), 
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('FieldName')!=null? 'Field': (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('TableName')!=null? 'Form':  (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('VIID') !=null? 'Visit' :(#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('PtId') !=null?'Pt':'Site' )))),
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('PtId') !=null? result :'-'), 
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('VIID') !=null? #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('VISID') :'-') , 
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('INSTID')!=null? #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('INSTID'):'-'), 
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('TableName')!=null? #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('TableName').replace('form.',''):'-'), 
                        (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('FieldName')!=null? #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('FieldName'):'-'), 
                        #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('CreatedBy'),
                        #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('QuerySubmitted').toLocaleString());        
            }
                                    });
                if (#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('FieldName') !=null && #{QueryDetailsWindow}.hidden)   {
                                updateSpot(#{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('FieldName').replace('[','').replace(']',''), #{QueriesStore1}.getAt(rowIndex).get('INSTID'));  
                              }

                              } catch(err){};
                              " />
```

Comment: What is the implementation of the callFNGetPtidPrfx method? If this method performs an asynchronous operation, it will probably not return anything.

Comment: second code block is not complete, missing second argument of String.format

Comment: @NBO Fixed that... Error still there

Comment: Is this something you can use? 
https://gist.github.com/astepin/c1e8aed6025ae01471ab47f7a46ed6bf

Comment: @ArtemStepin thank you it worked... but please take a look at my edited post. there is still a problem